# How to keep formatting of entered comments in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

In my site: [http://www.indiacustomercare.com](http://www.indiacustomercare.com/airtel-digitaltv-iptv-customer-care-contact-helpline-call-center-numbers) which Drupal 6 and I've set default format as "Full HTML".
Now people are sometimes entering long comments and when published, all newlines get removed and multiple paragraphs coalesce to become single para.

So what I'm doing is to copy it and paste the comment in design view in Dreamweaver. This inserts  br element, as entered by the user.

Is there any way this could be handled automatically in Drupal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Full HTML" is "Full HTML". It doesn't have the "Line break converter" input format filter turned on because that would be incorrect behaviour. If you want automatic line breaking, I recommend that you create a new input format and give it the filters that you want - including Line break converter.